# Mixing incremental divs and markdown in RMarkdown slides

Tags: r, r-markdown

I've been working with RMarkdown for a bit now for slide presentations. One item I noticed is that to implement 'appears' in slides using slidy ir ioslides, one had to wrap relevant sections in div or span tags with class="incremental".  This works like a charm, *except* when one includes additional text formatting, say **bold** or *italic* formatting. Those text elements are the incremented after the text.  So, for example

```
<div class="incremental">Hello **world**!</div>
```

would lead to the following, if each slide were me hitting the forward arrow once

Slide 1:
Blank

Slide 2:
Hello         !

Slide 3
Hello **world**!

Thoughts on a straightforward solution? The presentation option is otherwise amazing!

Comment: Have you tried using typical HTML instead of mixing-in markdown? `<i>world</i>` or `<b>world</b>`?

Comment: Yep, that works. But, one reason I'm using markdown is to minimize extra HTML. Frankly, having to use divs reduces my ability to go back and forth to other formats that parse markdown already, so I'd love to see if there's a solution there (there was in slidify with ~ which doesn't work in the current Rmarkdown for presentaitons).

Comment: And larger problem where this can't be avoided - any use of mathjax with the incremental class. Equations versus text pop up with odd and undesirable timing.